# MySQL Query Order

Tags: mysql, sql

```
$SQL->query('SELECT `p`.`name` AS  `name`,
  (SELECT `k`.`value` FROM `player_storage` k WHERE `k`.`key` = 1000  AND `k`.`player_id` = `p`.`id`) AS value
    FROM `player_storage` k, `players` p WHERE `k`.`player_id` = `p`.`id` GROUP BY  `name` ORDER BY CAST(`value` AS SIGNED) DESC LIMIT 0 , 30;
```

### PLAYERS

```
id | name   
1    test
```

### PLAYER_STORAGE

```
player_id | key | value 
1          1000   10
```

The query works fine the only is problem that the order is not correct, idk why.

Example:
[image]

Comment: You are selecting two columns and output has only one column. Check your example

Comment: 1. Why do not use a join instead of a subselect? 2. Are you sure that cast(value as signed) returns the value you expect and not just a bunch of zeros?

Comment: Another thing is there is a query, issued from php, and then there's this sort of html table rendering or whatever. Isn't there some intermediary post-processing stuff happening?

Comment: 1. Because i dont know what i'm doing, i have no knowledge in queries and i got this result just doing tests... the only problem is the order.

2. Yes, the original query works fine with cast(value as signed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example will return two columns, you're only ordering the second column.